# How to start my an Activity when home Button Pressed in android 10 or higher

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I want  my app start again after some time when it goes in background by pressing home button. That is app is not killed but still in recent. How to Achieve it in android.

I have tried using service but the problem is that the intent is not called automatically. it only opens when clicked on notification. somebody please help...

Comment: You cannot force your UI into the foreground from the background on modern versions of Android, except in [very limited circumstances](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts).

Comment: Users don't want your app to come to the foreground if they have put it in the background. That is annoying. This is by design.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT"/>
```

This helps launching an activity when device screen is turned off (only for use with extremely high-priority notifications, add function call `Notification.Builder setFullScreenIntent(...)`). [More info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean)).

And grant the overlay permission the app to be able launching an activity when other apps is running in foreground. Ask user to enable this permission by this way

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent overlayIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(overlayIntent, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is not working, Whenever app goes in background it just stops the process of intent.

Comment: It works with pending intent and alarm manager, or work manager